# Image sent by server doesn't display

Tags: php, c++, sockets

I'm using C++ as server and php as client, sending image via socket from server back to client. the main trouble that i receive image on client, but it's completely white. in html there are picture 1920*1080 without any picture. Can u suggest me where looking for a mistake ?

**server** part of image loading:

```
iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}

// Accept a client socket
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}

// No longer need server socket
closesocket(ListenSocket);

// Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
do {

    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult > 0) {
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);



     /*send file*/
        int fd;
        int sockfd;
        ssize_t nbytes;
        char buf[LEN];
        memset(buf,0, LEN+1);
        int len;

        FILE *in = fopen("desktop.png","rb");
        while ((iResult = fread(buf,sizeof(buf),1, in)) > 0) {
            send(ClientSocket,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
        }



        if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return;
        }
        printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);

    }
    else if (iResult == 0)
        printf("Connection closing...\n");
    else  {
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

} while (iResult > 0);

// shutdown the connection since we're done
//iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}

// cleanup
closesocket(ClientSocket);
WSACleanup();
```

so i'm packing image and send it to client.

**client**

```
function connect($host)
{
    //$host    = "127.0.0.1";
    $port    = 27001;
    $message = " testing."
    echo "Message To server :".$message;
    // create socket
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
    // connect to server
    $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");  
    // send string to server
    socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
    // get server response

    $buf;
    if (!socket_recv($socket, $buf, 4096, MSG_WAITALL)) {
                echo "Socket Receive Error...\n";
                $error_msg = 'Unable to receive data: ' . socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
            } else {
                echo 'BIND_TRANSMITTER Response: ' . var_dump($buf) . "\n"; 
    }

    $imgData = base64_encode($buf);
    $img = "<img src= 'data:image/png;base64, $imgData' />";
    print($img);

    socket_close($socket);
}
```

When i'm looking in html i see next details:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, 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">
```

So picture is on page with it's width and height, and there is a rectangle with that picture, but it don't displayed, only white background. I don't understand where is my mistake, can you please suggest me something ?

****UPDATE****
i'm change my server send block to.

```
    while ((len = fread(buf,sizeof(buf),1, in)) > 0) {
        send(ClientSocket,buf,len,0);
    }
```

now i think trouble on client, cause on server it's write error : *recv error failed with error 10053*

Comment: You have to remember that when sending data over a TCP socket, you may not receive all data in a single call to `recv`, you may need multiple `recv` calls.

Comment: You also have *undefined behavior* with your `memset` call. You have an array of `LEN` bytes but write `LEN+1` bytes. And you `send` always `sizeof(buf)` bytes, no matter how many bytes you read from the file. And where do you assign to `iSendResult`? There are probably more problems, but those are the ones I found with just a quick glance.

Comment: Oh and regarding my first comment, using `MSG_WAITALL` doesn't really work with a streaming protocol like TCP, it will wait until the requested number of bytes (in your case `4096`) have been received, no matter how much was sent.

Comment: please look again, i'm updated my server part. can you gime example of server php cycle of recv, i'm searching and it always one responce..in fact server write, that send 1088 bytes.

Comment: 1) Lose the space between the base64, and the image data itself. 2) have you tried manually decoding the base64 content received by the client and making sure it's the same as the desktop.png file?

Comment: yes i try, but now i cannot correctly get on php client bytes. i send from server 1920 and on client there are only 1, don't understand

Comment: Ok i'm analyse what i write, and there is a mistake on server side, but how can i send data in another way  ?